# Do while problems when trying to loop if condition is not attain

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, do-while

I'm trying to have my program work by inputting an integer between 10-50 and if they didn't input within the acceptable range the loop will go back by making them input again. But I can't seem to understand why my program doesn't work. I know the logic behind but I think the codes is the problem. Here is my code

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a digit between 10 and 50 ");
xx = Console.ReadLine();
x = int.Parse(xx);
do
{
    if (x > 10 && x < 50)
        Console.WriteLine("Pleae input again: ");
}
while (x <= 10 && x >= 50);
Console.WriteLine("The number is in between!");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Change `(x <= 10 && x >= 50)` to `(x <= 10 || x >= 50)`

Comment: The problem is that you don't grab input inside the loop.  The variable x never changes once you enter the loop.  (In addition to what clover said)

Comment: But i guess that the && will not make a difference since it's constraining the digit to be just between 10 to 50.

Comment: @user3806140: yes it will. `x` can not be smaller than 10 AND bigger than 50 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `if` condition is wrong, and the `while` condition is wronger!**

Try this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a digit between 10 and 50 ");
do
{
    xx = Console.ReadLine();
    x = int.Parse(xx);
    if (10 <= x && x <= 50)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Pleae input again: ");
}
while (true);
```

Comment: 2 things, not wronger it's more wrong... Number 2 the OP should also use tryParse in another if statement for input validation otherwise it will throw an error when they enter a character instead of a number... unless they want it to throw an error then it is fine :)

Comment: @developerIntern53718: Thank you for the English lesson. I did not really mean that one was "more wrong" than the other, just wanted to emphasize that the entire logic was generally incorrect.

Comment: @developerIntern53718: As to the exception issue, since OP's code is not given inside a method, there is no way to tell anything about it, therefore no point in addressing that issue.

Comment: That makes sense I know they didn't ask for it probably because they don't know to ask for it though...

Comment: @developerIntern53718: I agree, but you can infer from the question at hand that he or she has much more basic issues to learn before getting into exception, etc., point being, giving them "a lecture" about exceptions wouldn't be very effective to begin with...

Comment: I actually do a lot of tutoring in basic programming at a college level and this is actually very helpful... If you take time to explain this to them now it helps them understand the more advanced topics later... I'm not saying explain everything about exception handling but explaining the basics of using tryParse vs Parse is very valid at this level... This is irrelevant at any point currently because your answer does do everything the OP asked for :)

Comment: Hey thanks, but i have a question. What does "unreachable code detected" means? When I'm fabbling around my code on the while being true/false the if inside and the console writeline outside suddenly displays it

Comment: @user3806140: It means that you have a piece of code which will never be reached during runtime. If you're having problems understanding where exactly that piece of code is, then please publish that in a separate question, as it's a little hard for me to answer it without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Oh, just by explaining it makes me enlightened. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
    string xx;
    int x;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a digit between 10 and 50 ");
    bool cont = true;
    do
    {
        xx = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(xx, out x) && 10 <= x && x <= 50)
            cont = false;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Pleae input again: ");
    }
    while (cont);
```

Seeing `while(true)` makes my skin crawl.  And, you should always use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` for user input.

Comment: Do `while(true);` instead and use a `break` statement.  Then remove the `else`.  This will shrink it by 2 lines.  :)

Comment: Yea, you're hilarious.  And, it would shrink by 2 lines (removal of the cont variable declaration, and the else) - that's it.  The cont=false would be replaced by a break.

Comment: while(true) is an awful structure for code.  break statements should be avoided whenever possible.  I'm serious too.

Comment: Who taught you that?  As long as you know how to use `break` statements correctly, then it's perfectly fine to use them.  There is a topic on that on this site actually..

Comment: In a small loop like this - not really terrible I suppose; however, it can make readability and traceability of more complex code difficult.  And - that was reiterated in just about every software development class I've taken.  I'm less concerned with 2 more lines of code - and more concerned with code maintainability.

Comment: And that thread was closed as not constructive.  Let's not continue that debate here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IF and WHILE conditions.. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a digit between 10 and 50 ");

do
{
    xx = Console.ReadLine();
    x = int.Parse(xx);
    if (x <= 10 || x >= 50)
        Console.WriteLine("Pleae input again: ");
}
while (x <= 10 || x >= 50);
Console.WriteLine("The number is in between!");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: This is my first code, it doesn't work and just gives me unreachable code detected.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask for the input each time or you wont come out of the loop.

```
    do
     {
      xx = Console.ReadLine();
      x = int.Parse(xx);  
      if (x > 10 && x < 50)
          Console.WriteLine("Pleae input again: ");
     }
    while (x <= 10 && x >= 50);
    Console.WriteLine("The number is in between!");
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: He still won't come out of the loop. It will loop while `x` is smaller than 10 and x is bigger than 50...

Comment: This has a redundant check for the value of x - not really ideal.